# Grouping Elements with Muenchian Method

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I am trying to group all the same AsstTp together, according to the first element in their node. So all Scty elements go under one AsstTp element and all Csh elements go under another AsstTp element. As below:

```
<RpTrad>
<AsstTp>
  <Scty>
    <Id>
      <Id>GB00B3KJDQ49</Id>
      <ClssfctnTp>DBADGC</ClssfctnTp>
      <QtyOrNmnlVal>
        <NmnlVal Ccy="EUR">1000000</NmnlVal>
      </QtyOrNmnlVal>         
    </Id>
  </Scty>
</AsstTp>
<AsstTp>
  <Scty>
    <Id>
      <Id>GB00B3KJDP50</Id>
      <ClssfctnTp>DBADGC</ClssfctnTp>
      <QtyOrNmnlVal>
        <NmnlVal Ccy="GBP">1100000</NmnlVal>
      </QtyOrNmnlVal>         
    </Id>
  </Scty>
</AsstTp>
<AsstTp>
  <Scty>
    <Id>
      <Id>GB00B3KJDR51</Id>
      <ClssfctnTp>DBADGC</ClssfctnTp>
      <QtyOrNmnlVal>
        <NmnlVal Ccy="CHF">1200000</NmnlVal>
      </QtyOrNmnlVal>         
    </Id>
  </Scty>
</AsstTp>
<AsstTp>
  <Csh>
    <Id>
      <Id>US1234567890</Id>
      <ClssfctnTp>EABCDE</ClssfctnTp>
      <QtyOrNmnlVal>
        <Qty>10000</Qty>
      </QtyOrNmnlVal>         
    </Id>
  </Csh>
</AsstTp>
</RpTrad>
```

Should become...

```
<RpTrad>
<AsstTp>
  <Scty>
    <Id>
      <Id>GB00B3KJDQ49</Id>
      <ClssfctnTp>DBADGC</ClssfctnTp>
      <QtyOrNmnlVal>
        <NmnlVal Ccy="EUR">1000000</NmnlVal>
      </QtyOrNmnlVal>         
    </Id>
  </Scty>
  <Scty>
    <Id>
      <Id>GB00B3KJDP50</Id>
      <ClssfctnTp>DBADGC</ClssfctnTp>
      <QtyOrNmnlVal>
        <NmnlVal Ccy="GBP">1100000</NmnlVal>
      </QtyOrNmnlVal>         
    </Id>
  </Scty>
  <Scty>
    <Id>
      <Id>GB00B3KJDR51</Id>
      <ClssfctnTp>DBADGC</ClssfctnTp>
      <QtyOrNmnlVal>
        <NmnlVal Ccy="CHF">1200000</NmnlVal>
      </QtyOrNmnlVal>         
    </Id>
  </Scty>
</AsstTp>   
<AsstTp>
  <Csh>
    <Id>
      <Id>US1234567890</Id>
      <ClssfctnTp>EABCDE</ClssfctnTp>
      <QtyOrNmnlVal>
        <Qty>10000</Qty>
      </QtyOrNmnlVal>         
    </Id>
  </Csh>
</AsstTp>
</RpTrad>
```

I am currently trying to use the following XSLT, but it seems to just repeat what I have 4 times:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common">

<xsl:key name="Coll-by-AsstTp" match="AsstTp" use="local-name()" />
<xsl:template match="RpTrad">
    <xsl:for-each select="AsstTp[count(. | key('Coll-by-AsstTp', local-name())[1]) = 1]">       
        <xsl:for-each select="key('Coll-by-AsstTp', local-name())">
            <xsl:copy-of select="/node()" />
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

So I believe there is something wrong with creating my key and using the local-name() function not picking up the correct element value it needs to. Thus causing the for loop to run to many times and not going the level deeper to only copy the inner node of each AsstTp.

Thanks in advance,
Saul

Comment: Please delete your previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56293632/combine-contents-of-elements-with-the-same-name-over-an-xsl-template

Comment: @michael.hor257k sure done. Just an issue now is to get it working on top of the other transformations I have from that previous question. Will give it a go with your below answer. Thanks!

Comment: If you have other transformations to perform, then use `xsl:apply-templates` instead of `xsl:copy-of` and add templates matching the nodes you want to change.

Comment: @michael.hor257k The issue is the other transformations need to be applied first to create this structure. The original XML does not look much like the example I have given here for this grouping. I have applied my original templates into a variable and then am applying templates with mode="mPass2". Just struggling to see where we would create the key for example. Should I give it a go and post another question on this?

Comment: If your entire structure is held in a variable, you could use something like `<xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($firstPass)/RpTrad/AsstTp[count(. | key('asstTp-by-child', local-name(*))[1]) = 1]">`. But it's hard to see why you would want to create a structure in step one that must be modified in step two. Why not create the structure you need to begin with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to group `AsstTp` elements by the name of their child element - so your key should be defined as:

```
<xsl:key name="asstTp-by-child" match="AsstTp" use="local-name(*)" />
```

Then:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="asstTp-by-child" match="AsstTp" use="local-name(*)" />

<xsl:template match="/RpTrad">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="AsstTp[count(. | key('asstTp-by-child', local-name(*))[1]) = 1]"> 
            <xsl:copy>    
                <xsl:copy-of select="key('asstTp-by-child', local-name(*))/*"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will return the result you want.

---

**Note**:

The instruction:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="/node()" />
```

will copy the entire XML document, starting at the root node, regardless of the current context.